# Efficient computation of marginalized multivariate normal posterior distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

In general,if we know that the marginal Gaussian distribution for some variable $\textbf{x}$ and a conditional Gaussian distribution for some $\textbf{y}|\textbf{x}$ of the forms:
$$p(\textbf{x}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu},\Lambda^{-1})$$

$$p(\textbf{y}|\textbf{x}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{y}|A\textbf{x}+\textbf{b},L^{-1})$$
then the marginal distribution of $\textbf{y}$ and the conditional distribution of $\textbf{x}|\textbf{y}$ are given by:

$$ p(\textbf{y}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{y}|A\boldsymbol{\mu}+\textbf{b},L^{-1}+A\Lambda^{-1}A^{T})$$
$$p(\textbf{x}|\textbf{y}) = \mathcal{N}(\textbf{x}| \Sigma \left\{ A^{T} L ( \textbf{y} - \textbf{b} ) + \Lambda \boldsymbol{\mu} \right\} , \Sigma)$$

where :
$\Sigma = (\Lambda + A^{T}LA)^{-1}$

In my situation, I have a prior and likelihood: $$\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_p\sigma^2_\beta)$$
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} | \boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\beta},\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}).$$
Where $\hat{\textbf{S}}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\hat{\textbf{R}}$ is a symmetric correlation matrix. By making substitutions I arrive at the following marginalized likelihood :

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}|\sigma_\beta^2 \sim N(0,\sigma_\beta^2\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}^{-2}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}}+\hat{\textbf{S}}\hat{\textbf{R}}\hat{\textbf{S}})$$

My question is this, if I want to find the value of $\sigma_\beta^2$ that maximizes the marginalized likelihood, do I have to recompute the cholesky of that entire covariance matrix from scratch every time I try out a new value of $\sigma_\beta^2$, or do I have other options?

Comment: As I understand, in order to evaluate the log-likelihood, you need to compute 2 terms: matrix product with inverse covariance (1st term) and log determinant of covariance (2nd term). Even if you somehow optimize the calculation of the 1st term, isn't the second term still expensive?

Comment: WIth a cholesky or eigenvalue decomposition of the covariance matrix, the determinant is $O(N)$

Comment: But you want to avoid calculating a decomposition, right? AFAIK, there is no way of computing a determinant faster than using a decomposition.

Comment: I want to compute the decomposition once, and not have to recompute the decomposition for different values of $\sigma_\beta^2$

Comment: Of course you do. But you get different matrices for different values for $\sigma^2_{\beta}$, so they would result in different decompositions. Why do you believe that it is possible to have an algorithm where you perform the decomposition only once?

Comment: For the case where $\hat{\textbf{S}}=\text{diag}(1)$ (or I think any constant), you can use the eigenvalue decomposition of $\hat{\textbf{R}}$ (see my cross-post https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36236/efficient-computation-of-marginalized-multivariate-normal-likelihood)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I finally see your point. For a very specific form of $\hat{\textbf{S}}$ you have a matrix whose eigenvalues depend linearly on $\sigma^2$, which simplifies the problem significantly. However, the general problem you are solving has a non-linear dependence, which makes it fundamentally complicated.